# Project 2 Human Pyramid Calculations

Tags: python, recursion

For simplicity we will assume that everyone in the pyramid weighs exactly 200 pounds. Person
A at the top of the pyramid has no weight on her back. People B and C are each carrying half of
person A's weight. That means that each of them is shouldering 100 pounds.
Now, let's look at the people in the third row. Let’s begin by focusing on person E. How much
weight is she supporting? Well, she’s directly supporting half the weight of person B (100
pounds) and half the weight of person E (100 pounds), so she’s supporting at least 200 pounds.
On top of this, she’s feeling some of the weight that people B and C are carrying. Half of the
weight that person B is shouldering (50 pounds) gets transmitted down onto person E and half
the weight that person C is shouldering (50 pounds) similarly gets sent down to person E, so
person E ends up feeling an extra 100 pounds. That means she’s supporting a net total of 300
pounds.

Write a recursive function (using no loops), weightOn(r,c), which returns the weight
on the back of the person in row r and and column c. Rows and columns are 0-based,
so the top position is (0,0), for example, and person H is in position (3,1). The following
also hold:
weightOn(0,0) == 0.00
weightOn(3,1) == 425.00
Weights should be floating-point numbers.

I have already tried a lot. I will include my most recent code below.

```
t = 0.0
x = 0.0

def weightOn(r, c):

    global t
    if r < 0:
        print('Not valid')
    elif r == 0 and c == 0:
        return t
    elif r > 0 and c == 0:
        t += 200 / (2 ** r)
        return weightOn(r - 1, 0)
    elif r > 0 and c == r:
        t += 200 / (2 ** r)
        return weightOn(r - 1, 0)
    elif r > c > 0:
        mid(r, c)
        return t

def mid(r, c):

    global x
    x = weightOn(r - 1, c - 1) + weightOn(r - 1, c)
'''I have also tried: x = (((weightOn(r - 1, c - 1) + 200) / 2) + ((weightOn(r - 1, c) + 200) / 2))'''
    return x

r = int(input('r: '))
c = int(input('c: '))
weightOn(r, c)
if r > c > 0:
    print(x)
else:
    print(t)
```

It always brings up the wrong output. I can correctly pull up all of the edges (when c == 0 or c == r). But other than that it won't work.

Ex. Input (3, 1) outputs 500
(3, 2) outputs 550

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly "doesn't work". Show what the output was when you tried running it. Was there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global variables suggests that you haven't considered this recursively.

Each person shoulders half the weight of the persons on each shoulder.  The effective weight of each person is what they shoulder, plus 200 pounds.  If a person is on the edge, then the "person" on the other shoulder has 0 weight.

So ...

```
def weight(r, c):
# Code base cases
if r < 0:            # Past the pyramid top; no such person
    return 0
if c < 0 or c > r:   # Off the edge; no such person
    return 0
return 200 + (weight(r - 1, c - 1) + weight(r - 1, c)) / 2
```

Then `weightOn` is simply the above routine without the `200 +`.

That's your outline; can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def weight_on (r,c):
    
    second_person = 200 #finds out if there is a second person on top or not
    if c - 1 < 0 or c > r - 1 :
        second_person = 0
    if c < 0 or c > r:
        return 0
    elif r <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (second_person + 200 + weight_on (r - 1,c - 1) + weight_on (r - 1,c))/2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098), as that helps to improve the quality of your post. Consider also taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and see [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for further reference.