# Recursive method to calculate the weight a person is supporting in a human pyramid

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, methods

I've been banging my head against a wall for the past couple days trying to figure out the right way to set up this recursive method. I found another post on stack overflow that pointed me in the right direction, but can't figure out how to finish it up.

In a human pyramid, weight is not evenly distributed among the different people in
the pyramid. For example, person A has no weight to bear. If we assume that every person in our
pyramid weighs 200 pounds, then person B and person C each bear half of person A's weight (100
pounds each). Person E is directly supporting half the weight of person B (100 pounds) and half the weight of person E (100 pounds), so she’s supporting at least 200 pounds. Additionally, she's carrying half that person B and C are carrying, so an extra 100 pounds.

[Full program description here.](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106x/cs106x.1192/assignments/recursion.html)

This is what I have so far:

```
public int weightOn(int row, int column) {
    // Base cases
    if (row <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (column < 0 || column > row) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (200 + (weightOn(row - 1, column - 1) + weightOn(row - 1, column))) / 2;
}
```

The program works for the first 2 rows of the pyramid and all of the side people such as: weightOn(0, 0) = 0, weightOn(1, 0) = 100, weightOn(2, 0) = 150, but when I run weightOn(2, 1) I get 200, when it should be 300 or weightOn(3, 1) returns 275 when it should be 425.

Comment: Could you review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982663/project-2-human-pyramid-calculations

Comment: @sc0der I checked out that answer, but I don't understand what Prune meant by "Then weightOn is simply the above routine without the 200 +." If you remove 200+, you'll just always return 0?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach.
Just define a class that rappresent a node in you diagram. 
Each of this node may have (or not have basing on who this node rappresent) a link to the others nodes (min 0, max 2 like in a binary graph).
So now defining your weightOn function is pretty simple.
The weight of a node is

```
public int weightOn() {
    return 200 + leftNodeParent.weightOn()/2 + rightNodeParent.weightOn()/2 ;
}
```

Basically you'll obtain a recursive call on the method weightOn().

EDIT:
this should do the work

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Node a = new Node(null, null);
    Node b = new Node(null, a);
    Node c = new Node(a, null);
    System.out.println(c.weightOn());


 }

public class Node {
    Node leftParent;
    Node rightParent;
    public Node(Node left, Node right){
        this.leftParent = left;
        this.rightParent = right;
    }
    public int weightOn() {
        int leftWeight = leftParent != null ? leftParent.weightOn()/2 : 0;
        int rightWeight = rightParent != null ? rightParent.weightOn()/2 : 0;
        return (200 + leftWeight + rightWeight) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it needs to be done without the use of other classes, abstract data types, or loops.

Answer (score 0):

A -> BC -> EFG -> ... etc
Each level has a carried weight (n) , carries half that number (n/2) + what that level was already carrying , so each element carries a weight of ( (n/2) + what is already carried /2 ) , [ for instance in the second level we have B and C with a total of 400 , they carry 400+0/2=200 , so each element carries 200/2=100 ] 
[ another example for EFG : n = 200*3 and that level carries a total of 600 , so if we use our formula we ll find out that the weight is 450 so each element has weight of 150 ]

Comment: Weight is not evenly distributed in a human pyramid. In the 3rd row, made up of 3 people, the 2nd or middle person of that row would be supporting more weight than the 2 people to either side.

Answer (score 0):

Same as your idea but some basic changes..

```
public static int weightOn(int row, int column) {
    // Base cases
    if (column < 0 || column > row)
        return 0;

    if (row == 0)
        return 200;

    int w1 = weightOn(row - 1, column - 1);
    int w2 = weightOn(row - 1, column);
    System.out.println((row - 1) + " " + (column - 1) + " " + w1);
    System.out.println((row - 1) + " " + (column) + " " + w2);

    return 200 + (w1 + w2) / 2;
}
```

Now you can call the function like this to get the answer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(weightOn(4, 2) - 200);
}
```

I have just done basic testing ..

But the idea is, when ever a method a is called, you need to return its weight + part of the weight it gets from its parent (parentwt)/2;
At any point weight current node holding is parentwt/2;
So I have substracted 200 in sysout statement.